# Why does my class's test program return 0.0 for my answers?

Tags: java

```
package Geometry;

public class TestGeometryPoint {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Creates the object PointA and Assigns values
    Point pA = new Point(); //PointA(0, 0)
    pA.setX(2.0); //PointA(2.0, 0)
    pA.setY(5.0); //PointA(2.0, 5.0)

    //Creates the object PointB and Assigns values
    Point pB = new Point(4.0, 6.1); //PointB(4.0, 6.1)

    //Calculates the distance between PointA and PointB
    double d = pA.distance(4.0, 6.1); //Distance from class to a set of coordinates
    double dP = pA.distance(pB); //Distance from class to another point
    double dPtP = Point.distance(pA, pB); //Distance from point to point

    //Prints the result of the calculations
    System.out.println("Distance between Point A & B: " + d);
    System.out.println("Distance between Point A & B: " + dP);
    System.out.println("Distance between Point A & B: " + dPtP);
}
```

}

This is my Test Class and my Point class below.

```
package Geometry;

public class Point {

//Initializes the coordinates for a point on a graph with the values of x and y
private static double x;
private static double y;

//Defualt Constructor
public Point() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

//Point Constructor
public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

//Returns the x value
public double getX() {
    return x;
}

//Changes the x value
public void setX(double x) {
    Point.x = x;
}

//Returns the y value
public double getY() {
    return y;
}

//Changes the y value
public void setY(double y) {
    Point.y = y;
}

//Calculates the distance between the class's point coordinates and another set of point coordinates
public double distance(double x0, double y0) {
    double distance = (Math.sqrt(((x0 - x) * 2.0) + ((y0 - y) * 2.0)));
    return distance;
}

//Calculates the distance between the class's point and another Point class's location
public double distance(Point p) {
    double distance = (Math.sqrt(((p.getX() - x) * (p.getX() - x)) + ((p.getY() - y) * (p.getY() - y))));
    return distance;
}

//Calculates the distance between a Point class's location and another Point class's location
public static double distance(Point p1, Point p2) {
    double distance = (Math.sqrt((Math.pow((p2.getX() - p1.getX()), 2.0) + (Math.pow((p2.getY() - p1.getY()), 2.0)))));
    return distance;
}
```

}

d, dP, dPtP: all return 0.0 when compiled and run, but I have no idea why as I have tried changing code and checking my math when calculating distance. I think I might just need a new set of eyes to take a look at it.

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you don't name your classes to shadow JDK ones. We already have a [`Point`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html).

Comment: `private static double x;`. Oops.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem! And my professor chose the name for the classes, not me. Haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe since your x and y variables are static, they belong to the class Point as a whole. When you create a Point(2,5); 
You set the static variable of the class Point to be 2 and 5 and then, you create another Point(4,6) You set the same static value of x and y to be 4,6. 
Therefore, comparing the distance between the same two Point are 0.

The right code for the class Point would be like so

```
public class Point {

//Initializes the coordinates for a point on a graph with the values of x and y
private double x;
private double y;

//Defualt Constructor
public Point() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

//Point Constructor
public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

//Returns the x value
public double getX() {
    return x;
}

//Changes the x value
public void setX(double x) {
    this.x = x;
}

//Returns the y value
public double getY() {
    return y;
}

//Changes the y value
public void setY(double y) {
    this.y = y;
}

//Calculates the distance between the class's point coordinates and another set of point coordinates
public double distance(double x0, double y0) {
    double distance = (Math.sqrt(((x0 - x) * 2.0) + ((y0 - y) * 2.0)));
    return distance;
}

//Calculates the distance between the class's point and another Point class's location
public double distance(Point p) {
    double distance = (Math.sqrt(((p.getX() - x) * (p.getX() - x)) + ((p.getY() - y) * (p.getY() - y))));
    return distance;
}

//Calculates the distance between a Point class's location and another Point class's location
public static double distance(Point p1, Point p2) {
    double distance = (Math.sqrt((Math.pow((p2.getX() - p1.getX()), 2.0) + (Math.pow((p2.getY() - p1.getY()), 2.0)))));
    return distance;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have just always been taught to do static in my classes since high school and never even knew what it did besides reference the class itself.

Comment: No problem ! You shouldn't need to use static quite often normally. Its only used for very specific situations.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are confusing **static** and non-static fields.

By putting that little **static** on your field declarations you are saying: all instances of this class should be seeing the exact same variables.

So, when you create two points

```
p1 = new Point(5, 5);
p2 = new Point(10, 10);
```

the declaration of p2 "overrides" the 5-5 from p1 ... because, as said: all Points are using the **same** x and y.

Thus, solution: simply drop that keyword from the definition of x and y. Then each point has is very own x and y.

And, more importantly: understand that each and any character in your source code matters. This means: you better understand each and any concept that your source code is making use of!

Comment: While the other comment shows me how to fix it and what the issue is, your comment really helps to explain what static does to a field. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. And if you found my answer to answer your question, feel free to accept it than. Good for your and my reputation ;-)